# Django staging and formatting data into fields

Tags: sql, django

Say I have a poor quality data feed that represents different lengths (ex. 200ft, 50m, 8mmx60m). I want to convert this data to meters and store it as an integer. The problem is that I won't be able to catch all the discrepancies, and I'll have to convert some of it manually.

I want to be able to view the missed data in my Django admin page so I can easily go through and update it, rather than having to go back and forth between my feed.

My hack solution is to just have the data stored in a `CharField` and have a separate column that sets the row as live or staged depending on if `is.digit()=true`. Then I can go into the Django admin, reformat the data manually, and run a script that checks whether or not the data should be set to live.

There will be multiple sets of data like this (diameter, weight, etc.).

Other options I've considered:

1. Have staging columns that are `CharFields` and live columns that are  `IntegerFields`.
2. Have a staging table with `CharFields`.
3. Have a entire separate database for staging.

Any ideas? I'm new to Django and SQL so I don't know the best way to go about this.

edit:

Currently I have:

```
data       islive
60         true
70         true
70 meters  false
```

Option1:

```
data  data_raw
60    60
70    70
NULL  70meters
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternate option number 1 sounds the best to me, with the `IntegerField` using `NULL` to represent the lack of data. These are the advantages that I see:

1. Keeping the original text data around gives you more flexibility. What if there's a bug in your script? What if you decide you want the conversion to have more precision? Keeping the original data makes it easy to recompute later. And if at some point you decide you really don't need the old data anymore you can just drop the column.
2. Representing integer data in an `IntegerField` is better data modeling, and could make various things easier (not having to manually convert to and from integers all the time, using `F()` expressions, etc.).
3. There's no need to have a separate live column, and a separate step to compute it. 'live' just means `int_data__isnull=False`.

Comment: Per your point #3: If I don't have a separate "raw_data" column, I'll have to go back and forth between the .xml file. Having it as a CharField is very convenient, because I can just go in, delete the "meters" part, and I'm good.

Comment: Also there will be new data coming in daily with different products, so I'll have to merge the raw data into some kind of table regardless.

Comment: @dmb: Are we misunderstanding each other? I *am* suggesting that you keep the raw input data in a `CharField`. What I mean by point 3 is that you don't need a third (boolean) column to indicate whether the data has been converted or not, since that is implicit in whether or not the `IntegerField` is `NULL`.

Comment: Oh whoops. We're on the same page, then. Thanks for the input!